# How would I set up behat to check to see if I am on a route with a dynamic number?

Tags: php, bdd, behat

In behat I would like to check to see if the route I am going to is the correct route, the only issue is everytime I visit the route the number changes. How would I set up my behat to look for any number after wards and let it pass. So what I have is:

Then I should be on "/clinic/participant/create/{id}"

That bracket {id} will always be dynamic and if possible I would like to either ignore the last id or put a wildcard of some sort on it to say whatever is passed here works as long as its a number.

This is my work around, but I would still like to know if there is a easier way / cleaner way to do this.

```
public function iShouldBeOnRoute($url)
{
    $urlArray = explode('/', $url);
    $urlPath = $this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl();

    $urlPathArray = explode('/', $urlPath);
    $testedUrl = join('/', $urlArray) . end($urlPathArray);

    $this->assertSession()->addressEquals($testedUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this URL is an existing link that you can actually see, then you could create a custom step that gets the href attribute and then visit that url.

For example:

`I am on create participant page`

this step should contain: 
- find element -> get attribute href, save it in a variable 
- use visit with that variable

The css selector used should be:

```css
a[href*='/clinic/participant/create/']
```

If you have the id and you only need to check that the url contains that id you could just use a strpos !== false and throw exception or an assert.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not a existing link that I will go to, the route is generated by the database. So I click save and it sends the data to the database and then the database creates the route depending on the most recent id.  So in behat I need to look for that id. I made a work around not sure if its the best but I put it In my original message.